# How to compare 3 ArrayLists and get the differences in 3 new ArrayLists?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have 3 ArrayLists. the first list is constant and always has 7 values (Days of a week).

```
ArrayList<String> allAvailableValues = new ArrayList<String>();

allAvailableValues.add("MON");
allAvailableValues.add("TUE");
allAvailableValues.add("WED");
allAvailableValues.add("THU");
allAvailableValues.add("FRI");
allAvailableValues.add("SAT");
allAvailableValues.add("SUN");
```

The second ArrayList is a collection of Days (which will always be a subset of the First ArrayList).

```
ArrayList<String> existingList = DBmanager.getExistingDayList();

// sample output = {"MON", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT" }
```

The 3rd ArryList is also a collection of Days and again a subset of the First ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> newList = DBmanager.getUpdatedDayList();

// sample output = {"MON", "TUE", "THU", "SAT" }
```

Now, I have to compare the `existingList` and `newList`. From the above sample values, it's clear that:

1. "WED" and "FRI" has been removed in the new ArrayList.
2. "TUE" has been added in the new ArrayList.
3. No changes made in "MON", "THU", "SAT", "SUN"

Now I need to record the comparison result in 3 new ArrayLists.

```
ArrayList<String> values_to_be_removed = new ArrayList<String>();

// expected output = {"WED", "FRI"}

ArrayList<String> values_to_be_inserted = new ArrayList<String>();

// expected output = {"TUE"}

ArrayList<String> values_not_changed = new ArrayList<String>();

// expected output = {"MON", "THU", "SAT", "SUN"}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm working in a solution for your question that I will share in a few minutes. But it is almost mandatory on here to ask you: What have you tried so far?

Comment: why are  `MON, THU, SAT` not in `values_not_changed`?

Comment: jlordo - thank you for pointing out. I have updated the expected values.

Comment: Ignacio Alorre - I tried to use allAvailableValues.removeAll(existingList); and allAvailableValues.removeAll(newList). but not sure what to do next.

Comment: Im still a little bit confuse, why SUN appears in values_not_changed? SUN is not in existingList and newList

Comment: Ignacio Alorre - because all the changes of values are relative to the original list.

Comment: @BuggyCoder, converting to set will do the trick for you

Comment: I still dont see why SUN is in values_not_changed. "MON", "THU", "SAT" are in existingList and newList. But SUN is only mentioned in the original List

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre That's exactly why it's in values_not_changed I  guess. existingList and newList means they use those values. No one use "SUN" so he belongs to values_not_changed.

Comment: @PhoenixWang Ok, in that case MON, THU and SAT should not be in the same list, because they are used in both list. Well I guess values_not_changed groups all elements that were not used in existingList and newList or that were used in both list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just loop through it, and use a bunch of if statements to check what happened to it, using the contains function.

If the value was in the old list and now is in the old one, then add it to the "inserted list". The opposite would result in the day being added to the "removed list".

Also: Since your output for didn't change only seems to apply if the old and new list didn't contain that day, I'm going to assume that's what it's supposed to contain.

Here is an example:

```
for(String day : allAvailableValues){
    boolean inOld = existingList.contains(day);
    boolean inNew = newList.contains(day);
    if(inOld == false && inNew == false)
        values_not_changed.add(day);
    else if(inOld == true && inNew == false)
        values_to_be_removed.add(day);
    else if(inOld  == false && inNew == true)
        values_to_be_inserted.add(day);
}
```

Comment: This is the shortest piece of code block that addresses my problem, so marking this as accepted answer. thank you.

Comment: Although I think, line 7 and 9 should be swapped.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 2):

Java Collections are developed to work with them as you were working with sets in a  [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory))....

You can find easily:

**union**: Elements in Col. A merged with  all elements in Col. B

**intersection**: Elements common between  Col. A and Col. B

**complement**: Elements in Col. A but not in Col. B

[image]

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)

Comment: Regardless for this problem. This inspired me a lot for some other usage for Collections. Thx.